# I am reading csv file and what array_map() function does in this function?

Tags: php, csv, multidimensional-array, array-map

In PHP, I want to read a ".CSV" file using the following function.

```
function csv_to_array($filename='a.txt',  $header_exist=true, $delimiter="\t")
{
    if(!file_exists($filename) || !is_readable($filename))
        return FALSE;

    $header = NULL;
    $data = array();
    if (($handle = fopen($filename, 'r')) !== FALSE)
    {
        while (($row = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, $delimiter)) !== FALSE)
        {
            if($header_exist)
            {
                if(!$header)
                    $header = array_map('trim', $row);
                else
                    $data[] = array_combine($header, $row);
            }
            else
                $data[] = $row;
        }
        fclose($handle);
    }
    return $data;
}
```

and I am bit confused about `array_map()` function. I think it is supposed to map column names to each attribute is that so then how to fetch and display eacg attribute?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Opening a manual page for [`array_map`](http://php.net/array_map) you can see that:

> array_map — Applies the callback to the elements of the given arrays

So, you have a callback, which is `trim` (a core php function) and an array, which is `$row`. So, function `trim` now applied to each element of `$row`.

So, it is equivalent of:

```
$header = [];
foreach ($row as $item) {
    $header[] = trim($item);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In PHP, `array_map(function_name, array)` function sends each value of `array` to the `function_name()` and returns a new `array`.

In your case, The `$header` holds the `string` of column names separated by **`,`**'s. This means `array_map()` function converts them into an `array`.

Hope you get it.